# Unable to stop Metro Bundler correctly [Windows]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm developing React Native so I have to use `npm start` every time I want to develop. It's ok BUT when I want to stop my work, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to stop it. That was ok but it's been a while that i can't use npm start:

> **ERROR**  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081

I've run EVERY command I found on the net such as `netstat -abon | findstr ":8081"` to find the process but nothing...

Any way, I tried new port and use `react-native start --port=8082` but again, after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> OR closing the cmd, I can't use that port again. I used `8082`, `8083` and `6969` but I think it's not the correct way to stop that!

It was ok to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, I used this for about a year but now....

```
Environment:
  OS: Windows 8.1
  Node: 8.11.2
  Yarn: 1.7.0
  npm: 6.1.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Version  2.3.0.0 AI-162.3871768

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Any idea?

> Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the RN and restart the system.

Now i can stop the bundler with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.